# magento https/http redirection

Tags: mod-rewrite, magento, url-rewriting, apache-config, magento-1.4

Is there a way to redirect domains based on its parameters in magento.

Eg:

if user trying to load https://stage.domain.com/ the system should redirect it to 
  http://stage.domain.com/,

if user trying to load https://stage.domain.com/all_access_profile the system should redirect it to  http://stage.domain.com/all_access_profile ,

But the rest can goto its actual link what user actually requested.

I have got this one from @stackoverflow

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This one is always redirecting. How this needs to be changed to get url parameters based redirection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to redirect from the secure (https) to the insecure (http) but the rewrite rule `http%1` is directing to the secure. That is the wrong way round so it should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks but here  one more problem is the actual https links should be https. By using this way it rewrites everything to http. And Magento by default rewritting everything to index.php {RewriteRule .* index.php [L]} But this rewrite url doesnot work when we enter wrong url. page is broken instead of 404.